# Regex for detecting variables withing a boolean expression

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I wanted to parse names of variables within a boolean expression

for example from this string

*DOG* **AND** *ANDRES* **OR** *BAR* **OR** *BAND* **AND** (*COOL* **XOR** *DOG*)

I want to get variables

**DOG, ANDRES, BAR, BAND, COOL, DOG**

(doesn't matter if DOG is repeated)

I am new in building regex so I end up with this monstrosity

```
/(?!AND|OR|XOR|NOT)\b([\w]\w*)\b(?!\s*\()/g
```

The problem is that this regex confuses ANDRES with AND, how to ignore only full words?

I know regex is not capable of an arbitrary number of parenthesis, Is there any canonical way to do this?

Comment: "Is there any canonical way to do this?"

What language?

Comment: @HansZ Hello, it's intended to be a language agnostic question, but Java or Javascript could be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the word boundary in the negative lookahead as well:

```
(?!(?:AND|OR|XOR|NOT)\b)
```

Moreover, note that `[\w]\w*` could be simplified by `\w+`.

So to sum up, the following one should probably suit your needs:

```
(?!(?:AND|OR|XOR|NOT)\b)\b(\w+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/RgVaM1ee745wlT1C)

Comment: @HernánEche I believe your regex can be simplified, please see my edit.